# ¿Es este uso de subjuntivo en el pasado preposicional un error? "... tendría que seguir... cuando estuviera en París"

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

De *Cuando fui mortal* por Javier Marías:

> Lo único que me alertó ya entonces fue que, según me contó Silvia
>   entre risas, odiaba todo lo español, por lo que tal vez ella tendría
>   que seguir viéndome en los cafés y los cines cuando estuviera en
>   París.

Aquí, reconozco que hay un ejemplo del futuro del pasado, pero yo he aprendido que las preposiciones de tiempo solo usan subjuntivo en el futuro. Por lo tanto me pregunto: ¿es un error gramatical?

Comment: I understand you refer to "cuando" as a "preposición de tiempo". Actually, it's not a preposition but a conjunction. "estuviera" is subjunctive -- not present but past subjunctive (future from a past perspective). The sentence is perfect as it is.

Comment: @Gustavson I learned the definition linked by google auto-answer: "In Spanish, the subjunctive mode is used after “when” in temporal clauses referring to the future. " (http://download.langmaster.cz/grammar/en-gb/spanish2/grammar/les08/g04.htm). Spanish S.E. answers the question "Use the subjunctive after conjunctions of time to describe that something has not yet been observed."(https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/when-should-the-subjunctive-be-used-after-cuando) which doesn't exclude the past unlike the rule I learned. Maybe I'll wait to see if I encounter more real examples.

Comment: Just tried to give a detailed answer, but I'd advise looking for more examples as you said. The one in the text is not weird or quirky anyway, in case you were thinking that; rather it's absolutely typical, though not the pattern you've been taught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La oración es correcta, sólo que no es el mismo patrón que te han enseñado. El patrón que se usa aquí es del mismo tipo que el de las hipótesis con *si... entonces*:

> *si* **imperfecto-del-subjuntivo** *entonces* **condicional**

El modo condicional (el que termina en *-ría*) es lo que llamas "futuro del pasado".

Funciona de manera muy similar (en este caso) con *cuando* en vez de *si*:

> *cuando* **imperfecto-del-subjuntivo** *entonces* **condicional**

El orden puede invertirse, o bien se puede reemplazar ese *entonces* por otras palabras o expresiones, o por una simple pausa. Si el orden es como en el ejemplo que das, no se usa ningún *entonces*.

> **condicional** *cuando* **imperfecto-del-subjuntivo**
>   *tendría que... cuando estuviera...*

Este patrón usa el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo junto con un modo que representa el futuro de un pretérito, lo cual es de hecho bastante lógico, ya que ambos refieren al tiempo pasado.

Te enseñaron que sólo se usa el subjuntivo con *cuando* en caso de que el antecedente esté en futuro. Imagino que será algo así, usando tu ejemplo:

> *tendrá que seguir viéndome... cuando esté en París.*
>   **futuro-simple** *cuando* **presente-del-subjuntivo**

O sea, con el patrón en forma de condición para mayor claridad:

> *cuando* **presente-del-subjuntivo** *entonces* **futuro-simple**

Este patrón combina presente y futuro. Esto se debe a que el [futuro del subjuntivo](http://ec.europa.eu/translation/bulletins/puntoycoma/47/pyc475.htm), aunque existe, ya casi no se usa en castellano. (En vez de *cuando esté en París*, se diría más correctamente *cuando estuviere en París*.)